# Appending a line to a hosts file ONLY if it doesnt already exist

Tags: c#, streamwriter, hosts

My code looks like this;

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "drivers/etc/hosts")))
{
    w.WriteLine("127.0.0.1 www.google.com");
}
```

I want get rid of duplicates in hosts file. How can I check if line exists and prevent appending it again?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of existing duplicates or just prevent creating new duplicates?

Comment: prevent creating new duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a simple solution:
Just read all the text and check for the presence of your text. If  not write to the file.

```
string texttowrite = "127.0.0.1 wwwgoogle.com";
string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "drivers/etc/hosts"), Encoding.UTF8);
if (!text.Contains(texttowrite))
{
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "drivers/etc/hosts")))
    {
        w.WriteLine(texttowrite);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works very well, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little LINQ query to check if there's already a line:

```
bool exists = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "drivers/etc/hosts"))
    .Any(l => l == "127.0.0.1 www.google.com");
if(!exists)
    w.WriteLine("127.0.0.1 www.google.com");
```